# Matlab format from a script

Tags: matlab

if I set the display format from the command window by

```
format short e
```

I can cause values like `x = 1000000000000000000000`

```
x =
   1.0000e+21
```

to be displayed as the above in scientific notation, as above.

But any such values I enter in a script will not be displayed in scientific notation; but as entered. This, when I put format short e in the script.
I want to avoid counting zeros.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to work fine for me. What do you get if you write `format short e (new line) x = 1.23e12` in an otherwise empty m-file and run it? I get `x = 1.2300e+012`. This is what you want right?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you're describing ; I get `1.0000e+21`  when run in a script. How do you run the script (interactively, with Bash redirection, with `-r`) ?

Comment: Yes that works. But, if I use syms x (new line) f1 = 4.0e15 - 1.2e9 and run the script, I get  f1 =
 
4000000000000000*x - 1200000000  I run the script from the Matlab Editor Window in an Windows Virtual PC hosted on Windows 7

Comment: I think I did not understand that using the symbolic package means  that syms x real (new line) 5.1e14 * x is not treated as a number? class(5.1e14 * x) gives the type as sym. But why does Matlab expands the exponential coefficient? Is there some command in the Symbolic package to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign variables with large numbers you can write them like:

```
x = 10^5
```

which is equal to :

```
x = 100000
```

Comment: Also possible: assign variables in exponential notation: ``x = 1e5`` instead of ``x = 10^5``. It might also save computation time as ``10^5`` has to be evaluated.